# Debian: how to setup (bootable) HDD & clone OS to this drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, debian, clone, boot-partition

I got a Debian machine with 2 HDD (20GB each) computer only has one HDD slot. The second drive I want to make a clone of the first one so I can use the drive in case the main one fails.

How do I set up my drive to be exact clone (bootloader, partition, data) of the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, given that the two drives are of the same size, it is very easy, but you will have to use a live distro (Ubuntu?) to do this. The reason is that disks have to be unmounted to be cloned, and of course, if you start your pc from one of the HDDs, this HDD cannot be unmounted.

Start your pc from the USB stick with Ubuntu on it, and choose the option 'Try Ubuntu without installing it'. Now, assuming your USB stick is /dev/sdb, your system HDD is /dev/sda, and the back-up disk is /dev/sdc, issue this command as sudo, from a terminal

```
  dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc
```

wait for it to complete, turn the pc off, and you are done.

Only important thing is: make sure the disk to be copied is /dev/sda, and the back-up is /dev/sdc. If they are not, change the command accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, will this also copy partition info (swap files?)

Comment: @MariusMatutiae yes it will, just be careful when doing this. if= in file, of = outfile. Be careful not to mix up.

Comment: @DouglasDC3 yes it will, it is a true clone